# laravel 8 - can i access a variable inside a constant inside my config

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, string, config

I have a series of constant strings that I am using for an application, placed inside a file called gameconstants inside my config directory

I'm using the config() function to get various messages, so the file looks similar to this

```
return [

'furiouspunches' => ' furiously punches ',
'kick' => ' kicks $loser in the junk ',
```

Is there a way for me to access that $loser variable? I'm using these constants to return strings for an app I'm building, so I end up concatenating this returned value, and the final output is something like

```
$winner . config('gameconstants.kick') . $loser
```

But the strings don't always play nice with the way this is, so I would like to access that variable so I can return different variations of that string.

I've tried

config('gameconstants.kick.$loser')
but that doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use a string replacement, e.g.

```
return [

'furiouspunches' => ' furiously punches ',
'kick' => ' kicks {loser} in the junk ',
```

then

```
$string = $winner . str_replace('{loser}', $loser, config('gameconstants.kick'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use translation files instead of config files. Translation files also support parameter replacement.

Create a file at `resources/lang/en/strings.php`:

```
<?php

// resources/lang/en/strings.php

return [
    'furiouspunches' => ' furiously punches ',
    'kick' => ' kicks :loser in the junk ',
];
```

Then you access your string using the double underscore method (`__()`), and pass in the array of placeholder values:

```
$string = $winner . __('strings.kick', ['loser' => $loser]);
```

You can read up on the [translation documentation and variable substitution here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization#replacing-parameters-in-translation-strings).

---

Depending on your use case, you may want to include both items in the strings. Maybe something like this:

```
<?php

// resources/lang/en/strings.php

return [
    'furiouspunches' => ':subject furiously punches :object',
    'kick' => ':subject kicks :object in the junk',
];
```

Then pass in both replacements:

```
$string = __('strings.kick', ['subject' => $winner, 'object' => $loser]);
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply, I actually like the thought of using translation files. This seems like something I'll rework my application to take advantage of. Learn something new everyday :)